# JavaScript function is preventing link working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This javascript function is used to animate a number of selection boxes, however, I want to be able to use these selection boxes as A HREF links but i believe that something in this javascript is preventing it from acting as a href link.

Please could someone help point me in the right direction

Any help much appreciated thank you

```
(function() {

        var $container = $('#portfolio-items');

        if( $container.length ) {

            var $itemsFilter = $('#portfolio-items-filter'),
                mouseOver;

            // Copy categories to item classes
            $('article', $container).each(function(i) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass( $this.attr('data-categories') );
            });

            // Run Isotope when all images are fully loaded
            $(window).on('load', function() {

                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector : 'article',
                    layoutMode   : 'fitRows'
                });

            });

            // Filter projects
            $itemsFilter.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                var $this         = $(this),
                    currentOption = $this.attr('data-categories');

                $itemsFilter.find('a').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');

                if( currentOption ) {
                    if( currentOption !== '*' ) currentOption = currentOption.replace(currentOption, '.' + currentOption)
                    $container.isotope({ filter : currentOption });
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $itemsFilter.find('a').first().addClass('active');
            $itemsFilter.find('a').not('.active').hide();

            // On mouseover (hover)
            $itemsFilter.on('mouseenter', function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                clearTimeout( mouseOver );

                // Wait 100ms before animating to prevent unnecessary flickering
                mouseOver = setTimeout( function() {
                    if( $(window).width() >= 960 )
                        $this.find('li a').stop(true, true).slideHorzShow(300);
                }, 100);
            }).on('mouseleave', function() {
                clearTimeout( mouseOver );

                if( $(window).width() >= 960 )
                    $(this).find('li a').not('.active').stop(true, true).slideHorzHide(150);
            });

        }

    })();
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the browser from following the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

`e.preventDefault();`